# Apply a high-pass filter to a WAV file with scipy.signal.firwin

Tags: python, audio, scipy, signal-processing

I'm trying to apply a high-pass filter (cutoff: 1000 Hz) to a mono 16-bit 44.1 Khz WAV file with [`scipy.signal.firwin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.firwin.html):

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
from scipy import signal
import numpy as np

sr, x = wavfile.read('test.wav')      # 16-bit mono 44.1 khz

b = signal.firwin(5, cutoff=1000, fs=sr, pass_zero=False)

x = signal.lfilter(b, [1.0], x)

wavfile.write('test2.wav', sr, x.astype(np.int16))
```

The result is totally similar to the input (but not exactly equal), i.e. no high-pass has been applied.

**What should I modify to make this high-pass with `firwin` work?**

Comment: `x = lfilt_result = signal.lfilter(b, [1.0], x)` Is it even Pythonic?

Comment: This was a wrong copy/paste @bipll, thanks, I edited the question. THe problem is still there after this fix.

Comment: @bipll Even if he didn't use it, I think it is Pythonic. Isn't it?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I confused it with augmented assignments. Simple assignments can be chained in Python, yes.

Comment: Even if it's *possible* to chain them in Python, I agree with you @bipll that it's not a good idea to do it: when seeing `a = b = c`, we never know what is assigned to what... Ugly (personal taste)!

Answer (score 3):

It seems the problem is only the number of coefficients of the filter: 5 was too low.

With

```
b = signal.firwin(101, cutoff=1000, fs=sr, pass_zero=False)
```

it works far better.

Note: the audio will be nearly zero during the first 101 samples, so we should probably zero-pad the WAV file at the beginning and end, then apply the filter, then crop the file to remove the zero-padded parts.

Comment: BTW, it says "numtaps must be even if a passband includes the Nyquist frequency" which is seemingly your case.

Comment: I tried with an even numtaps, but I had this error: `ValueError: A filter with an even number of coefficients must have zero response at the Nyquist frequency.`

Comment: Yes, the doc appears somewhat con(fusing|tradictory) here.

Comment: FYI: The mistake in `firwin`'s docstring was recently fixed: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/8849